# How can we ignore the tags with the hidden-link while we import tags of an Azure Application Insights

Tags: azure, tagging

while importing the tags of azure resources (key,value pair) is it possible to avoid the hidden tags.How can we achieve this ?
I used the below piece of code to get the tags.

```
$tag=""
        foreach($keys in $arr){
            $tag = $tag +$keys +":"+$tags[$keys]+"`n"
        }
        $report | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name ResourceTags -Value $tag
        $report | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name ResourceSubscription -Value $subscription_name
        $report | export-csv $fileName -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

[What does "hidden-link:" mean in Azure Resource Manager Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38578122/what-does-hidden-link-mean-in-azure-resource-manager-tags)

The above link shows the hidden-link for adding tags which hides a tag.

Can I get the hidden tags seperated from the list of all tags.

Comment: what do you mean `hidden tags`?

Comment: @JoyWang hidden-link that is passed in tags section . This link would be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38578122/what-does-hidden-link-mean-in-azure-resource-manager-tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($keys in $arr){
       if($tags[$keys] -ne "Resource") {
        $tag = $tag +$keys +":"+$tags[$keys]+"`n" }
```