# How to convert an array into properties of one object in an ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I am looking for a way to convert an array (e.g. of strings) into one object, where the properties are generated from the array values.

Use case: I want to generate a `tags` object with links to resources, based on a list of resource names. I need to do this, to [link `App Service` resources to an `Application Insights` resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38578122/what-does-hidden-link-mean-in-azure-resource-manager-tags).

The list of resources could be supplied using a parameter:

```
"parameters": {
  "appServices": {
    "type": "array",
    "metadata": {
      "description": "Names of app services to link this application insights resource to via hidden tags"
    }
  }
}
```

Sample input:

```
['appName1', 'appName2', 'appName3']
```

Sample output:

```
"tags":
{
  "[concat('hidden-link:', resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/', 'appName1'))]": "Resource",
  "[concat('hidden-link:', resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/', 'appName2'))]": "Resource",
  "[concat('hidden-link:', resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/', 'appName3'))]": "Resource"
}
```

I know you can use [`copy`](https://learn.microsoft.comen-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/copy-variables) to loop over arrays but that will create an **array of objects** and **not a single object** (which is required for tags), for example:

```
[
{
  "[concat('hidden-link:', resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/', 'appName1'))]": "Resource"
},
{
  "[concat('hidden-link:', resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/', 'appName2'))]": "Resource"
},
{
  "[concat('hidden-link:', resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/', 'appName3'))]": "Resource"
}
]
```

It would be possible to use [`union`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-object#union) to merge those objects again, but that function requires you to hardcode the objects you want to merge, so it **does not work when you have an input with variable length**.

What I am looking for is a way to do this in a dynamic way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct option to convert array to object.
But here's a hack to achieve what you need. This will work for array of any length.

Steps:

1. append hidden-link text to service names
2. convert array to string
3. replace necessary symbols and make it a valid json string.
4. use json() to convert string to object

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "appServices": {
      "type": "array",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Names of app services to link this application insights resource to via hidden tags"
      },
      "defaultValue": [ "appName1", "appName2", "appName3" ]
    }
  },
  "functions": [],
  "variables": {
    "copy": [
      {
        "name": "as",
        "count": "[length(parameters('appServices'))]",
        "input": "[concat('hidden-link:', resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/', parameters('appServices')[copyIndex('as')]))]"
      }
    ],
    "0": "[string(variables('as'))]",
    "1": "[replace(variables('0'), '[', '{')]",
    "2": "[replace(variables('1'), '\",', '\":\"Resource\",')]",
    "3": "[replace(variables('2'), '\"]', '\":\"Resource\"}')]"
  },
  "resources": [],
  "outputs": {
    "op1": {
      "type": "object",
      "value": "[json(variables('3'))]"
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Now that [lambdas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/bicep-functions-lambda) have been [added to bicep](https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/4153) you can convert arrays to objects using `reduce`. Note that the array you reduce must consist of object items. If it doesn't you can convert it to an object using `map`.

```
// With array of objects
var names = [
  {
    name: 'foo'
    id: 'foo-id'
  }
  {
    name: 'bar'
    id: 'bar-id'
  }
]

var nameIds = reduce(names, {}, (cur, next) => union(cur, {
  '${next.name}': next.id
}))

output test object = nameIds
```

```
// With array of strings
var names = [
  'foo'
  'bar'
]
var nameMaps = map(names, (name) => {name: name})

var nameIds = reduce(nameMaps, {}, (cur, next) => union(cur, {
  '${next.name}': next.name
}))

output test object = nameIds
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best approach to this problem.

Tags are supposed to be metadata about a specific object/service.  [Wouldn't it make more sense to apply a tag (say your system name, environment, etc..) and then run a query against azure on that tag?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/tag-resources)

This should achieve the same result pulling back all related resources.

Comment: Normally, I would specify tags in a different way, yes, but in this particular case I'm using the syntax of "hidden-link:<resourceId>": "Resource" to link an App Service to Application Insights. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38578122/what-does-hidden-link-mean-in-azure-resource-manager-tags

Comment: Besides, knowing how to achieve the asked functionality (array transformation to properties of a single object) will give more freedom in writing ARM templates, so the usecase is just an example. There can be other valid cases.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is still relevant, but since 2021 it is possible to do with `items()` [function](https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/1427#issuecomment-916090630)

Comment: items() is the reverse of what the OP was looking for. It turns an object with key-value properties into an array of {key: <key>, value: <value>} objects. The OP wants to take an array of "string": "string" and turn it into a single object